# htaccess rewrite without extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo, friendly-url

I'm a beginner using htaccess and I don't know how to do what I want. I'd like to understand what I'm doing so I'd really appreciate if you can help me give me some advices for ver (very!) beginners... :)
I'd like to:
**Redirect xxx.php, xxx.html or any extension to xxx (without extension)**
Now, my htaccess is

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

and it works but just if I write xxx. But if I write xxx.php (I see the page :(, I'd like to redirect to xxx) and if I write xxx.html it doesn't show nothing.

Finally. I've like to rewrite variables to friendly links
i.e. If I have xxx.php?id=1 > I would like to redirect to xxx/username

Thank you in advance
Best wishes and merry christmas! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

If you need to do the same with with `.html` extensions, then change the `php` part of that condition to `(php|html?)`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! ;) <3
Would you mind to tell me how to convert xxx?id=1 into url/value, where name it's in the database under the var=val value. I will try to explain myself better: 
TABLE XXX
id > 1
name > value
I'd like to get the value for the id and put it into the URL... Sorry but my knowledge of htaccess is almost null :/
Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
I use this code already.

Rule:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Put this in your htaccess file && then check for files without extension.
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code makes the page open without extension but it doesn't redirect say `about.php` to `about` which is what OP asked for